# Clarification for Sahih al Bukhari 2476 about killing pigs

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, animals

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "The Hour will not be established until
> the son of Mary (i.e. Jesus) descends amongst you as a just ruler, he
> will break the cross, **kill the pigs**, and abolish the Jizya tax. Money
> will be in abundance so that nobody will accept it (as charitable
> gifts).

Can someone explain the bit about killing pigs? Why is that the case? I have heard explanations that pigs are filth except that there are a lot of other animals that are filth. What's so specific about pigs?

I also understand, that Allah created all animals to be treated with kindness. Does this references that pigs don't fit that category? That they are impure and should be exterminated. Or am I missing something else.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the cross and killing the pig are symbolic acts renouncing the Christian belief about Jesus, such as the belief that he had made pork lawful for them. It is also a practical way of forbidding people from eating and trading pigs. As such it is similar to other forceful methods of deterring sins like spilling wine and damaging musical instruments etc.

Keep in mind that killing certain animals is permitted / prescribed in Islam, for example the [fawasiq](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/120) and [snakes and some dogs](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2233b). In the same way killing pigs is generally considered [permissible](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/137989/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D9%82%D8%AA%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1) by the majority. Especially feral pigs may attack humans and damage crops, and any animal can be killed if it causes harm.

**Ref:**

> فيكسر الصليب ويقتل الخنزير أي يبطل دين النصرانية بأن يكسر الصليب حقيقة ويبطل ما تزعمه النصارى من تعظيمه ويستفاد منه تحريم اقتناء الخنزير وتحريم أكله وأنه نجس لأن الشيء المنتفع به لا يشرع إتلافه ... ويستفاد منه أيضا تغيير المنكرات وكسر آلة الباطل
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3626)</sup>

> وفيه دليل أن الخنزير حرام في شريعة عيسى ، وقتله له تكذيب للنصارى أنه حلال في
> شريعتهم
>
> <sup>— [Sharah Sahih Bukhari](https://shamela.ws/book/10486/2969)</sup>

Comment: Killing for the sake of self defence and sustenance is understable. Yet killing for making a statement? Not all christians considering pork lawful, given it's mentioned in the bible. If it's about making a statement, I breaking the cross or destroying churches in the end of days, is more appropriate. Killing pigs? I am not too sure. Unless the Hadith is somehow referring to pigs turning feral or dangerous in the later days then it makes sense.

Comment: Most Christians *do* consider pigs to be lawful, those who do not are in a clear minority. You say that this is not appropriate way to make the statement, but that is just your opinion and Jesus and would not really care about your opinion on the matter, rather he would do as he feels is necessary.

Comment: I do agree my logic was a little conflicting. We kill animal for our own sustenance and pleasure... so killing pigs to make a statement isn't far fetched

Answer (score 1):

> Ibn Hajar al-Asqalani in his explanation of this Hadith said: “Pigs
> are killed to show that it is prohibited to be eaten. It is also an
> insult to the Christians who claimed that they are the followers of
> Prophet Jesus, but then they ruled it halal to eat swine and like it.”
> Fath al-Bari bi Sharh Sahih al-Bukhari, 4/414

Comment: I am confused by the explanation. There's a lot of other animals that are prohibited to be eaten, what so special about pigs? So killing pigs would be about making a statement?